# Storing "meta" data on redis job is not working?

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I'm trying to test a queued redis job but the `meta` data doesn't seem to be passing between the task and the originator.  The job_id's appear to match so I'm a perplexed.  Maybe some fresh eyes can help me work out the problem:

The task is [as per the documentation](http://python-rq.org/docs/jobs/):

```
from rq import get_current_job

def do_test(word):
    job = get_current_job()
    print job.get_id()
    job.meta['word'] = word
    job.save()
    print "saved: ", job.meta['word']
    return True
```

The `rqworker` log prints the job_id and word after it is saved

```
14:32:32 *** Listening on default...
14:33:07 default: labeller.do_test('supercalafragelistic') (a6e2e579-df26-411a-b017-8788d621149f)
a6e2e579-df26-411a-b017-8788d621149f
saved:  supercalafragelistic
14:33:07 Job OK, result = True
14:33:07 Result is kept for 500 seconds.
```

The task is invoked from a unittest:

```
class RedisQueueTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Requires running "rqworker" on the localhost cmdline
    """
    def setUp(self):
        use_connection()
        self.q = Queue()

    def test_enqueue(self):
        job = self.q.enqueue(do_test, "supercalafragelistic")
        while True:
            print job.get_id(), job.get_status(), job.meta.get('word')
            if job.is_finished:
                print "Result: ", job.result, job.meta.get('word')
                break
            time.sleep(0.25)
```

And generates this log showing the same job_id and correct result, but the `meta` variable `word` is never populated.

```
Testing started at 2:33 PM ...
a6e2e579-df26-411a-b017-8788d621149f queued None
a6e2e579-df26-411a-b017-8788d621149f finished None
Result:  True None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried adding a long delay so the log has a chance to see the task in `started`, but not finished state (in case meta is cleared when it finishes), but it didn't make any difference.

Any idea what I've missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The local job doesn't automatically update itself after a `save` occurs at the remote end. One must do a `refresh` to update it.  Before the refactoring this was not necessary as I was doing a `fetch_job` with the job_id on every request.

So the test routine needs to include a `refresh()` (or fetch_job) to reflect any changes:

```
def test_enqueue(self):
    job = self.q.enqueue(do_test, "supercalafragelistic")
    while True:
        job.refresh()     #<--- well, duh, freddy
        print job.get_id(), job.get_status(), job.meta.get('word')
        if job.is_finished:
            print "Result: ", job.result, job.meta.get('word')
            break
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

Which works a bit better:

```
Testing started at 5:14 PM ...
6ea0163f-b5d5-411a-906a-f765aa0b3cc6 queued None 0 []
6ea0163f-b5d5-411a-906a-f765aa0b3cc6 started supercalafragelistic
6ea0163f-b5d5-411a-906a-f765aa0b3cc6 finished supercalafragelistic
Result:  True supercalafragelistic
```

The fact that the `get_status` was updating fooled me into overlooking this: `get_status()` is a method that goes as looks for the current status, whereas `meta` is just a pointer to some *possibly stale* data somewhere.

Comment: +1 for the solution. I was also confused by job.meta.save() stuff. Please feel free to accept this as answer :p